# Could an application capture and log a user's actions on another 3rd party software. If yes, how?

Tags: software-engineering, security, applications

Could an application be built such that it could track a user's actions on a particular software and log them?
For example, could an application track a user's actions on MS Word, noting down when the user clicked a particular button?

The question is asked assuming, our application has no access to the code of the 3rd party software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about computer science, it's about a specific operating system. (The answer is yes on most OSes, but this is due to engineering choices, not scientific considerations.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Read about [keyloggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging), [spyware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyware), and screen capture software.  See also related topics on Security.SE, e.g., https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=keylogger, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyloggers, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spyware, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/201449/971, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/102434/971, https://security.stackexchange.com/q/238842/971